# How to extract H264 video from RTP packets in a .pcap file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, wireshark, h.264, rtp

I am using FFmpeg to transmit RTP stream of a video and then capture and save all packets using WireShark into a .pcap file. The FFmpeg command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.264 -r 25 -video_size 352x288 -c:v libx264 -f  rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Now, I want to convert back to video using this pcap file. Can FFmpeg do this? or Is there other tools available?

Also, I want to test how packet loss affects the quality of video. So I need to drop several packets in the pcap and then convert back to video to see the effect. Can I get the video back just use the rest of the packets in the pcap file?

To achieve the goal I said above, I also need to learn which packets are corresponding to what kind of frames right? So can I acquire the type of frames only looking at the RTP packets in the file. How can I do that?

Comment: "Also, I want to" => You need to limit this to one question so that future readers can benefit from this as well. Please read the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in full.

Comment: If you can post a capture file somewhere containing a sample  H264 video stream, then someone might be able to help you with a method of extracting the video.  I don't work with RTP much so I can't give you a definitive answer, but you might want to have a look at Wireshark's *"Telephony -> RTP -> RTP Streams"* dialog, which offers an *Extract* feature and which may or may not help you here.

Comment: There's a Wireshark plugin, look for `rtp_h264_extractor.lua` or something like that.